# open source soap engine for c#

Tags: open-source, c#, web-services, soap

I need an open source C# SOAP engine. Something like wsdl.exe tool the gets WSDL and generate classes.
I want to get to know how WSDL pulls out all methods and parameters

I want a liberary that gets WSDL and generate SOAP strings for sending and also generate SOAP strings returns.

Remember, being open source is important.